# Navigation bar to the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, nav

I am designing a web page. I have already created the navigation bar but the problem is that I want it on the right side of the page. I have tried using `float: right` but it does not work. It works perfectly when scrolling the page as it moves to stay in place, but I have not been able to send it to the right side of the page, like for two days.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Here is my HTML, I am skipping the Hero Section as it is another div.

```css
.sideNav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  bottom: 4.5vh;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 60px;
  float: right;
}

.sideNav__button {
  padding: 8px 8px 24px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Navegation bar -->
  <nav class="sideNav d-flex flex-column">
    <!-- Navegation icons -->
    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/inicio_off.png" alt=""></a>

    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/lulu_off.png" alt=""></a>

    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/menu_off.png" alt=""></a>

    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/about_off.png" alt=""></a>

    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/reserva_off.png" alt=""></a>

    <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="./res/icons/contacto_off.png" alt=""></a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For demonstration purposes, I changed your logos to dummy images. If you don't want your `sideNav` class to have a `width: 100%;` you can change the `width: fit-content;` and give your `.sideNav` a flex display and use `align-items: flex-end;` to align the content to the right. PLease see the changes I made below to your CSS.

```css
.sideNav {
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.sideNav__button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- Navegation bar -->
    <nav class="sideNav d-flex flex-column">
        <!-- Navegation icons -->
        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>

        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>

        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>

        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>

        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>

        <a class="sideNav__button" href="#"><img class="navIcon" src="https://dummyimage.com/25x25/000/fff" alt=""></a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (`right:0;` and remove `left:0;`) :

```css
    .sideNav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        background-color: red;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1 !important;
        bottom: 4.5vh;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding-top: 60px;
        float: right;
    }
```